# IE8 jQuery error at line "elem[ type ]();"

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am having trouble using jQuery 1.7.2, 1.8.0 or 1.8.3 in IE8. The webpage works well in Chrome, Firefox, IE9, Safari, and Opera.

In IE8 it prompts the following error in the developer tools:

`Can't move focus to the control because it is invisible, not enabled, or of a type that does not accept the focus`

This error happened on line 2973 in jQuery 1.8.0 and 1.8.3 (in 1.7.2 it is line 3242): `elem[ type ]();` which exist inside the `trigger` function.

How can I solve this problem? Or at least know which `trigger` execution caused this problem.

Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: take a look at: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10859

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading this post http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10859 (pointed by @nez in the comments). I searched for `.focus` calls inside my code and it was about 50 calls distributed among third parties like jQuery-ui, jquery.validate and my code itself. I decided to change jQuery 1.8.3 itself instead of changing a bunch of other third part libraries.

So I changed the following line 2973 in jQuery-1.8.3.js:

```
elem[ type ]();
```

to:

```
try {
  this.newelement[0].focus();
} catch(err){}
```

Comment: yeah, I am having this problem because of jQuery UI (which I can't really modify). I am going to try your fix.

I wonder if (and hope) newer versions of jQuery fix this bug. More realistically, I wish that my user base would freaking upgrade from IE8 (20% still uses it in Sept 2015, WTF?). FYI, in my code it was line 2972

Answer (score 1):

This is an old as heck bug in IE (glad to know it's fixed in 8). I don't know the official cause, but I believe it has to do with IE not repainting the DOM until after the execution context is complete, meanwhile trying to `focus()` the element while it thinks it's still hidden:

```
function calledAtSomePoint() { // begin execution

    // ...

    element.style.display = ''; // show container
    input.focus(); // IE thinks element is hidden 

    // end of execution, IE repaints the DOM but it's too late
}
```

[The solution is to use `setTimeout`](http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/focus-is-not-working-in-ie-solution/):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('add-comment-login-overlay-username-input').focus()
}, 0)
```

I've had it happen many-a-time, including with jQuery. It's no fault of any library. The `setTimeout` has always worked around it for me.